# How to get part of xml as string

Tags: c++, xml, c++11, xml-parsing, qt5

I saw similar questions in other languages but not in Qt using c++. I can only get one string which is a xml data. In this string data there are more than one xmls. First has instructions for me and the other I should only copy to another file. Like in this example:

```
<response>
    <path>C:/foo.xml</path>
    <language>en</language>
    <xmlToCopy>
        <someField1>
            <nest1></nest1>
            <next2></next2>
        </someField1>
        <someField2>bar</someField2>
    </xmlToCopy>
</response>
```

Untill now I've been using QString to get substring which begins with `<xmlToCopy>` and ends with `</xmlToCopy>` but it's very error prone and slow. Are there any other possibilities of getting part of xml between specific fields?

EDIT1:
I'm parsing this xml with 2 steps:

1. Using QXmlStreamReader for parsing fields which I expect (in this example: "path" and "language").
2. Using substring to cut text under xmlToCopy field

Content under field xmlToCopy is unknown and I don't want to read it. I only want copy it to other file.

EDIT2:
I want to extract from example above only this:

```
<someField1>
    <nest1></nest1>
    <next2></next2>
</someField1>
<someField2>bar</someField2>
```

And saves it to file.

Comment: Qt has xml parsing builtin. Are you forced to write your own (partial xml parser) instead of using the builtin xml support?

Comment: What is the expected result array? {"<nest1></nest1><next2></next2>",  "bar"} or what else?

Comment: I just editted post to clarify what I want.
@drescherjm I don't want to build my own parser. I'm just asking for a better way to get desired text.

Comment: @decltype_auto I expect to get text under xmlToCopy field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after some struggling, the following could should give you what you want:

```
QByteArray xml = "<response>                               \n"
                 "    <path>C:/foo.xml</path>              \n"
                 "    <language>en</language>              \n"
                 "    <xmlToCopy>                          \n"
                 "        <someField1>                     \n"
                 "            <nest1></nest1>              \n"
                 "            <next2></next2>              \n"
                 "        </someField1>                    \n"
                 "        <someField2>bar</someField2>     \n"
                 "    </xmlToCopy>                         \n"
                 "</response>                              \n";

QXmlStreamReader reader(xml);

qint64 start = 0;
qint64 end = 0;
while (!reader.atEnd()) {
    if(reader.isStartElement() == true) {
        if(reader.name() == "xmlToCopy") {
            start = reader.characterOffset();
        }
    }

    if(reader.isEndElement() == true) {
        if(reader.name() == "xmlToCopy") {
            end = reader.characterOffset();
            QByteArray array = xml.mid(start, end - start - QByteArray("</xmlToCopy>").size());
            array = array.trimmed();
            qDebug() << "XML to Copy: \n" << array;
            qDebug() << "OR : \n" << array.simplified();
        }
    }
    reader.readNext();
}
if (reader.hasError()) {
    qDebug() << "error: " << reader.errorString();
}
```

The assumption is that you have a `QByteArray` that the reader works on.

The output is:

```
XML to Copy: 
 "<someField1>                     
            <nest1></nest1>              
            <next2></next2>              
        </someField1>                    
        <someField2>bar</someField2>"
OR : 
 "<someField1> <nest1></nest1> <next2></next2> </someField1> <someField2>bar</someField2>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try the [QXmlStreamReader::readElementText()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxmlstreamreader.html#readElementText) function?

From the documentation it sounds like it does what you want:

> Convenience function to be called in case a StartElement was read. Reads until the corresponding EndElement and returns all text in-between.

```
QString text = xmlReader.readElementText(QXmlStreamReader::IncludeChildElements);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it's not what I want to archive. This method only cuts text from fields. I want to copy processing instructions as well (just added second edit to my post).

Comment: @Isaac Ok I see, I do not think this is possible except if you do something yourself :(